# Failure for Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromHICON

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, bitmap, gdi+

I'm trying to convert a `HICON` to `Gdiplus::Bitmap` by calling `Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromHICON` as shown below.

I created a windows icon by calling `LoadIcon`, and verified the icon is valid by drawing on screen.

Surprisingly, I still got a `NULL` pointer. I revisited the [win32 documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536292(v=vs.85).aspx) but cannot find what I'm missing.

```
HICON hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
assert( hIcon != nullptr ); // passed

Gdiplus::Bitmap *pIcon = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromHICON(hIcon);

assert( pIcon != nullptr ); // failed
```

Does anyone have some idea? Thanks:)

Comment: if you want idea - call `Image::GetLastStatus ` - may be this give you hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the GDI+ engine using the [GdiplusStartup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534077(VS.85).aspx) function first:

```
HICON hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
assert(hIcon != nullptr); // passed
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
Gdiplus::Bitmap *pIcon = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromHICON(hIcon);
assert(pIcon != nullptr); // now OK
GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't realize there are startup & shutdown methods.

Comment: Just curious, `HICON`'s height would behave differently depending on if  `hbmColor` is present or not (colorful or monochrome). Does the `Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromHICON` handle this properly?

Comment: @hackjutsu You should probably post that as a separate question.